# Webpack config - exclude axios module

Tags: vue.js, webpack, axios

I am importing axios something like in entry.client.js

```
window.Vue = require("vue");
window.Vuex = require("vuex");
window.VueRouter = require("vue-router");
window.axios = require("axios");
window.someMonoRepo = require("@monoRepo/repo");
```

and i want to exclude axios from the bundle

```
externals: {
    axios: "root axios",
    vue: "root Vue",
    vuex: "root Vuex",
    "vue-router": "root VueRouter",
    "@monoRepo/repo": "root someMonoRepo",
  },
```

i am able to exclude vue, vuex, vue-router and someMonoRepo but not axios. i still see axios bundle analyzer report.

With below snippet, I was able to exclude axios but i see an error `Uncaught ReferenceError: someMonoRepo is not defined`

```
 externals: [
    /axios*/,
    { vue: "root Vue" },
    { vuex: "root Vuex" },
    { "vue-router": "root VueRouter" },
    { "@monoRepo/repo": "root someMonoRepo" },
  ],
```